# How can i turn off automatic Request-Context httpHeader when using activitySource from System.Diagnostic

Tags: .net-core, system.diagnostics

I currently use ActivitySource and set some data in a baggage that i then use in a custom httpHandler. Everything is fine and all.
but when i add some baggage i get sometime this format error:

```
System.FormatException: The format of value 'MyApp%2F2022.1.0a5+(Windows%3B+U%3B+Windows+NT+10.0%3B+en)' is invalid.
   at System.Net.Http.Headers.NameValueHeaderValue.CheckValueFormat(String value) in /_/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/Headers/NameValueHeaderValue.cs:line 359
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.InjectHeaders(Activity currentActivity, HttpRequestMessage request) in /_/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/DiagnosticsHandler.cs:line 315
   at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /_/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/DiagnosticsHandler.cs:line 74
```

it turn out that by default on httpClient there is an Handler `DiagnosticHandler` that is added then this one fail while trying to create an `Request-Context`

```
 public HttpClientHandler()
    {
      this._underlyingHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler();
      if (DiagnosticsHandler.IsGloballyEnabled())
        this._diagnosticsHandler = new DiagnosticsHandler((HttpMessageHandler) this._underlyingHandler);
      this.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
    }
```

How can i turn this thing off?

Answer (score 1):

Okey so i posted my problem on the dotnet/runtime github and got an answer:
https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/57230

for me i decided to do:

```
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.EnableActivityPropagation", false);
```